# Value found in Excel but returns blank

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I am using `=INDEX(B:B;MATCH("milliseconds";A8;0))` and it finds the value I assume, but it comes back blank...im speechless

[image]

Comment: You should be matching on the whole column A: `=INDEX(B:B;MATCH("milliseconds";A:A;0))`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the data in A and B (not an image)

Comment: I always wonder if I should add as an answer seeing as @Rory has already answered the question.  At the moment the MATCH part of the formula - `=MATCH("milliseconds",A8,0)` is asking "where in the range of cells A8 does the word milliseconds appear" - it appears in cell A8, which is the first (and only) item in the list so it returns 1.  `INDEX` then returns the first item in the range B:B - which is cell B1 and blank.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Apologies for the bad question I was in a rush yesterday.

`=INDEX(B8,MATCH("milliseconds",A8,0))`